# How can I move the focus on a Treeview.item with pywinauto?

Tags: python, pywinauto

[OBJECT]
Treeview with several items.
I want to click on an item that is visible only after I scrolldown.
How can I move the focus on that Treeview.item with pywinauto ?
Note: I want to try to getItemNumber and then with typeskeys(down) move to that item.

```
[CODE]
treeItem = systreeview.GetItem([u'A', u'thisItemShouldBeClicked'])
treeUtem.Click()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
treeItem.EnsureVisible()
```

It scrolls TreeView down to the item so that you can `Click()` or `ClickInput()`.